# How do I position a form 3-cols from both sides without using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, django

How do I position the form(inside a card), 3-cols from both sides so the form lies in about 6-cols in the middle without using Bootstrap, Materialize or anything similar
Thanks

```html
  <div class="card">
  
      <div class="form_top">
        <h1>Form</h1>
      </div>
      
      <div class="field1">
        <label>Username</label>
        <span class="holder">{{ form.username }}</span>
      </div>

      <div class="field1">
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <span class="holder">{{ form.email }}</span>
      </div>

      <div class="field1">
        <label>Password</label>
        <span class="holder">{{ form.password1 }}</span>
      </div>

      <div class="field1">
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <span class="holder">{{ form.password2 }}</span>
      </div>
      
  </div>
```

What is looks like: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLcsQ.png

What it should look like: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYlJW.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Create the container and split it into 12 columns:

```
.card-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}
```

Tell the content to span 6 columns, starting at the 4th column.

```
.card {
  grid-column: 4 / span 6;
}
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/KKdXXow).

[image: visual of the grid columns]

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to the class "card". You want to place the card in middle so make margin from left side as well as right side.'margin-left' will place the card and 'margin-right' will restrict the card to move right side.
margin-left:*required width*
margin-right:*required width*

This works for me.Hope it will solve your query.

Comment: Maiti That's not an efficient way to solve this problem